# Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to get the value of the dropdownlist called ddlBrand the moment it is selcted so that I can use to dynamically change the items in another dropdownlist called ddlSubBrand which is in the same form.

This is the 2 drop down list in my AddProduct.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged" 
AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubBrand" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList><br /><br />
```

As for the code behind file, I have a page load to bind the Data from my sql to the drop down list and I have another method for the SelectedIndexChanged where I'm trying to get the value as soon as they select it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BrandManager brandManager = new BrandManager();
        CategoryManager categoryManager = new CategoryManager();
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            ddlBrand.DataSource = brandManager.getAllBrand();
            ddlBrand.DataTextField = "BrandName";
            ddlBrand.DataValueField = "BrandId";
            ddlBrand.DataBind();
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Value = "0";
            item.Text = "--Select Brand--";
            ddlBrand.Items.Insert(0, item);

            ddlCategory.DataSource = categoryManager.getAllCategory();
            ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
            ddlCategory.DataBind();
            ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
            item.Value = "0";
            item.Text = "--Select Category--";
            ddlBrand.Items.Insert(0, item);


        }

    }
    protected void ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(ddlBrand.SelectedValue);


    }
```

I seem to get an error that says :
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy pasted these lines and didn't change item to item1 and ddlBrand to ddlSubBrand

```
        item.Value = "0";
        item.Text = "--Select Category--";
        ddlBrand.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

So basically you are adding item twice to ddlBrand. If that's selected then you have 'multiple' items selected.

Change your code to:

```
        item1.Value = "0";
        item1.Text = "--Select Category--";
        ddlSubBrand.Items.Insert(0, item1);
```

Comment: I saw that too.   I think the error message is bogus, it should say something like duplicate item location.

Comment: But was this the answer that solved your question or did you see it before your post and you still have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario like below code

**Initially, We added ListBox for multiple role selection -**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstRoles" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>

 drpFunderName.DataSource = entities.GetRoles.ToList();
 drpFunderName.DataValueField = "ID";
 drpFunderName.DataTextField = "Name";
 drpFunderName.DataBind();
```

**In edit mode, We are displaying multiple roles-**

```
IList<RoleModel> roleModels = entities.Roles.Where(r => r.IsActive == true).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < roleModels.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lstRoles.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        if (roleModels[i].Id == int.Parse(lstRoles.Items[j].Value))
        {
            lstRoles.Items[j].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After changing **SelectionMode="Single"** and also using same logic for role selection as above (multiple selection) then error raise like **Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList Error**

You must change code for role selection in Edit form-

```
RoleModel roleModel = entities.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleId == 4);
if (roleModel != null && roleModel.RoleId.HasValue)
{
    lstRoles.SelectedValue =Convert.ToString(roleModel.RoleId.Value);
}
```